# Compilation error when a shared_ptr<string> is not initialized using initializers list

Tags: shared-ptr, initializer-list

In the following code, `pName_` has been initialized inside a constructor's body, which during compilation throws error as :

*error: no match for call to ‘(std::shared_ptr >) (std::string*)’*

*pName_(new string(name));*

However if i change the way it is initialized, by initializing it using initializers list, then it works fine. Why?

```
class Person
{
public:
        Person(string name) //: pName_(new string(name)){} /*UNCOMMENT THIS*/
        {
               pName_(new string(name));
        }
        void printName(){ cout<<endl<<*pName_; }
private:
        shared_ptr<string> pName_;
};

int main()
{
        vector<Person> persons;

        Person p("George");
        persons.push_back(p);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use initialiser list syntax in the body of the constructor - essentially you're calling the () operator on pName_ with the parameter of a string, this will not initialise your object and is the reason for the compilation error.

You should favour initialiser list syntax anyway as it means your member won't be default constructed, then thrown away and re constructed by the body of your constructor.

To compile, you either need to use the copy or assignment operators. I would also advocate the use of make_shared over operator new.

Comment: I didn't get it. You would get the same error even if you write a copy ctor for person to copy _pName